# Не добавляется пробел

Tags: c++, c++11

**Задание:** Собрать несколько строк в одну.

**Моя реализация:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    string result;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
        string st;
        cin >> st;
        result += st;
    }
    cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

**Проблема:** В переменную result не добавляется строка с пробелом.

**Пример:** При вводе строки вида aab bc. В переменную result добавиться только aab.

Comment: Читайте документацию. Оператор `>>` (ну, `cin >> st;`) читает **одно слово**. Кстати, так же, как и `%s` в `scanf`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scanf и cin читают всё до первого пробела

Comment: Я бы уточнил, что они читают до первого пробела при чтении `%s` и `>>`, и то по умолчанию (можно переписать оператор `>>` для другого класса, чтобы он читал строки, например). Тот же `scanf` легко может читать строку целиком, как и `cin` с помощью `getline`.